# Visual Studio 2017 Server Code upon starting makes a call to a controller I don't want

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, startupscript

Visual Studio 2017 - I inherited code for a server. Sits on an IIS port 60480 and waits for a call to a controller. At least that is what it is supposed to do.
[image]
When I press the green arrow next to Server (on the right), it starts and runs one of the test controllers.
[image]
The test runs correctly, but then when I close the test browser window, it stops debugging.  I don't want the test script to be called at all!

I'm afraid I don't know how this "script" is set up. So that I can change it.

What I want is for NO test function to be called at all; rather, it should just wait for a call to come in from the front end.

I appreciate any help.  Thanks in advance.
Chuck ("Yogi")

Comment: Are you're debugging the application or debugging the test :)

Comment: No.  My purpose is to have the server running and available on IIS and then test the FRONT-END sending messages to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If processor of emulator was set to X86 that cannot run your project in the emulator, but you set the processor to the armeabi-v7a, you can run your emulator normally, am I right?

If so, this issue was related to the [Hardware acceleration for emulator performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows).

Here are two ways to achieve that. Based on your description, you do not have Hyper-V, so you can choose the Intel's Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) to accelerate it.

Let check the following settings in your computer.

1. Disable the [disable Device Guard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/troubleshooting?tabs=vswin&pivots=windows#disable-devguard).
2. Then Verifying HAXM support, You said your computer have enabled the Intel VT-x, could you double check it like [this link](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005486/processors.html) ?
3. If your hardware supports HAXM, we can Open a command prompt window and enter the following command.

[image]

If the state is stop or not set to RUNNING, then HAXM is not installed. You can [download it](https://github.com/intel/haxm) and install it.